# CreateDXGIFactory fails with -2004942761 (0x887f0057)

Tags: c++, directx

I've written a 32-bit game in C++ using Visual Studio 2010 that mysteriously runs on various computers but not on others. I'm currently developing on Windows 10. The game using Direct3D (Directx10 and 11). On the computers that fail to run the game, I inevitably get an error result when calling CreateDXGIFactory (see title.) I am convinced something isn't installed properly, but I don't know what else to install. On every computer that Visual Studio 10 (the IDE in which I wrote the game) is installed, the game executes fine. (This may be a coincidence, I suppose.)

I'm completely out of ideas.

To test this out, I'm using a brand new Lenovo laptop (the game also will not run on a friend's desktop, by the way) from work running Windows 10. After my install (I created an install for my game using the generic Setup that comes with VS 2010), I run the game and it gives me the aforementioned error. My setup program has detected dependencies of: d3d11.dll, d3dx10_43.dll, d3dx11_43.dll, DINPUT8.dll, DSOUND.dll, dxgi.dll, Microsoft_VS100_CRT_x86.msm.  During the install process, the setup runs the setup for Microsoft DirectX Software Development Kit (not silently; the user must accept the agreement.) After the installation, I run the program and get the aforementioned error.

I then did the following:

- Uninstalled the game.
- Ran DxDiag; there are 2 displays: 1) Intel UHD Graphics P630; 2) NVIDIA Quadro p2000 W/ MaxQ
- Dxdiag told me I had DirectX 12 installed (and I'm trying to use 10 and 11, so those should be there.)
- I installed Visual C++ 2010 redistributables because I didn't see them there. (I ran into an error while installing and found online that I needed to uninstall the most recent ones before installing 2010.)
- Re-installed my game.
- Executed and got the same error.

Here is the first part of my initialize function that contains the code that creates the factory (the culprit is at the bottom, CreateDXGIFactory):

```
bool D3DClass::Initialize(int viewportWidth, int viewportHeight, bool vsync, HWND hwnd, bool fullscreen, float screenDepth, float screenNear)
{
    std::string sFn = "D3DClass::Initialize";

    HRESULT result;
    IDXGIFactory* factory;
    IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
    IDXGIOutput* adapterOutput;
    unsigned int numModes, i, numerator, denominator;
    size_t stringLength;
    DXGI_MODE_DESC* displayModeList;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
    int error;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferPtr;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc;
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    float fieldOfView, screenAspect;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthDisabledStencilDesc;
    D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendStateDescription;
    int adapterWidth;
    int adapterHeight;

    if (fullscreen)
    {
        adapterWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        adapterHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        adapterWidth = rc.right - rc.left;
        adapterHeight = rc.bottom - rc.top;
    }


    CHelpers::LogMessage(ige::FileLogger::LOG_INFO, sFn, "AdapterWidth=%d, AdapterHeight=%d", adapterWidth, adapterHeight);

    // Store the vsync setting.
    m_vsync_enabled = vsync;

    // Create a DirectX graphics interface factory.
    result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        CHelpers::LogMessage(ige::FileLogger::LOG_ERROR, sFn, "CreateDXGIFactory failed with result = %d", MAKE_DXGI_HRESULT(result));
        return false;
    }
```

When I run this on my development workstation, I get a result of 3666300 decimal when calling CreateDXGIFactory, which is expected and successful.

**IMPORTANT**: On my workstation desktop, in "Apps and Features", I see "Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)". I see NO SUCH thing on the Lenovo laptop, even though I've installed it repeatedly with success. Why??

I've spent scores of hours trying to figure this out and am at my wits' end. Can anyone help?

Comment: `CreateDXGIFactory()` return an `HRESULT`. DO NOT call `MAKE_DXGI_HRESULT()` on an `HRESULT`! That macro is meant to *create a new* `HRESULT` given a 16-bit error code, which you don't have. When logging the `result` of `CreateDXGIFactory()`, you need to log the `result` *as-is*, DO NOT log it as `MAKE_DXGI_HRESULT(result)`, you will corrupt the bits of the `HRESULT` value. `CHelpers::LogMessage(..., MAKE_DXGI_HRESULT(result));` needs to be `CHelpers::LogMessage(..., result);` instead. Then you will have a better chance of diagnosing the *real* error given an uncorrupted `HRESULT` in your log

Comment: Thanks, Remy. I'll change that.

Comment: You should take some time to read [Not So Direct Setup](https://aka.ms/dxsetup). While you are still using VS 2010, you should also read [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://aka.ms/dxsdk).

Comment: I don't know if your specific problem is this, but for Direct3D 11 you should avoid using "DXGI 1.0" which was created for Direct3D 10. Try changing to use ``IDXGIFactory1`` instead of ``IDXGIFactory``. You should also take a look at [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/)

Comment: Thank you, Chuck, I will look at those articles. Let me try changing the Factory method I'm using and I'll check back in.